# What kind of test cases can we not automate in selenium webdriver - java

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, webdriver, selenium2, java

I want to know what kind of test cases we cannot automate using selenium webdriver.

I do not want to use any 3rd party tool (Autoit, etc..)

What are the limitations of Selenium WebDriver?

Comment: IMHO this is too broad. You probably cannot test any low-level hardware stuff like CPU caches, memory throughput or driver memory leaks. I don't think it is really suitable for testing SAP GUI. I would not use it in a C# environment. You'd better not do any time critical image processing with it but use OpenCV instead. Basically, everything for which it was not designed to be used...

Comment: You cannot test my toaster with Selenium.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I know captcha (Some captcha you can test) you can not test using selenium webdriver.

Comment: Hopefully we can do this in the future. We had been able to read faces for a long time now: http://how-old.net

Answer (score 1):

- Gestures - User can perform multiple clicks on submit button / search button occasionally which could result in page reloads / transactions cancelled
- Image / Video Previews - Between transitioning between thumbnail and playback of videos I have observed not well automated
- Payment gateway timeouts - During peak transactions there could be timeouts with payment gateway. This depends on network throughput, time out which is really a production dependant scenario

Comment: I totally agree with siva's answer... And also with qa4it on the point of automating captcha! And i'd like to add that you cannot write tests for performance/load testing using webdriver...

Answer (score 0):

1- As you said you dont want to use any Third Party tool, then you can not handle windows browse or upload file button using selenium because its syntax is like this-

```
Example:
<input type="file" id="browsecv" name="browsecv"> /<input>
```

or

```
you can search it on below link and then inspect for **"browse"** button
link: http://my.naukri.com/manager/createacc2.php?othersrcp=9280&wExp=N
```

2- you can not handle any controls whose attribute or field is hidden. in simple you cannot handle Hidden element using Selenium.
3- CAPTCHA -> Either in the form of image or Number Can not handle by selenium.

Comment: I think you can handle hidden elements with the JavaScript executor without problems, not sure how a user would use hidden fields :)

Comment: you can check it on below link. try to click on browse button from below link you will get the idea. I have tried but no luck with javascript and selenium. link: http://my.naukri.com/manager/createacc2.php?othersrcp=9280&wExp=N

Answer (score 0):

You can't simulate a recovery from a system crash (either loss of internet or machine crash).  I'd usually cover these manually to ensure that the devs are posting data in an appropriate transaction (to avoid partial posts).

Answer (score 0):

- Bar code reader can't be tested.
- If you are using TestNG then you can do load testing,please read [this](http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/testng-selenium-load-testing-example/)

Comment: The reader can be tested, not the barcode generator. The reader is just a keyboard. You can just send the same keys the barcode-reader would generate. I have done this in the past to test thousands of combinations and see how the system would handle them.

Comment: Hi Niels,can you please tell me example or any reference?

Comment: @NielsvanReijmersdal - I'd respectfully disagree here. Using the keyboard buffer to simulate a barcode reader isn't actually testing the reader-software hookup: it's testing the software handling of expected barcode reader input. If the barcode reader is incorrectly configured or faulty, this method will not expose that problem.

Comment: @KatePaulk I understand. Often I take a shortcut and expect the supplier and operations to test their ends, but maybe I am to development team focused in my answers and comments.